# From where to start reading about ELK stack?

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana, elastic-stack

I am new to ELK and use mac as my personal machine but a PC in office.
Please help me in finding a right track to go ahead with ELK stack.

Comment: If you have a Pluralsight subscription, thats a good place to start. There are a few good tutorials there. The official documentation is pretty good as well. What is your goal with the Elastic stack? Administer? Develop for it using Java?

Answer (score 1):

[First of all use oficial docs it's very good](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/index.html)

[Tutorials for users](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials?q=elasticsearch)

[Info for aministration](https://www.datadoghq.com/search/?ref=blog-search&search_index=themonitor_english&s=elasticsearch&section=blog&support=)

Answer (score 1):

I'm currently at my work trying to setup the ELK stack as well, there are tons of guides, and honestly, all of them still require the user to tinker.

I have found [the official stack guide](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elastic-stack/current/installing-elastic-stack.html) to be the most helpful with my endeavours so far.

Though I have one recommendation: do not install from the apt-get repos, I've found those just....don't work for me. I've had the best luck just downloading their packages directly from them.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions

Answer (score -1):

Take a look into the following courses in Udemy

[Linux Academy's Elastic Certification Preparation Course](https://linuxacademy.com/cp/modules/view/id/257)

[Elasticsearch 6 and Elastic Stack - In Depth and Hands On!](https://www.udemy.com/elasticsearch-6-and-elastic-stack-in-depth-and-hands-on/)

[Complete Guide to Elasticsearch](https://www.udemy.com/elasticsearch-complete-guide/)

[Complete Elasticsearch Masterclass with Logstash and Kibana](https://www.udemy.com/complete-elasticsearch-masterclass-with-kibana-and-logstash/)

Comment: Please be a little more descriptive in your answer.